# Rewrite Join which introduces duplicate rows without DISTINCT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to get distinct `PLANS_T.ID` after a `JOIN` with a table, `CAREER_GOALS_T`, which can list multiple entries per `PLANS_T.ID`. As a result of that I'm getting duplicated PLAN IDs in my result.

The below is a simplified version. Many other fields are also being selected. I don't want to put `DISTINCT` on my `PLANS_T.ID` because my query should also return all cases where PLAN ID = NULL. The `DISTINCT` would be required if my criteria include `careergoals.goal_id in (..)`, but sometimes I don't have those criteria. I don't want to turn `DISTINCT` on/off in my code, I want a consistent query for all cases.

What I'm looking for is some other solution without a `DISTINCT` that would let me get unique `PLANS_T.ID` for any matching Join result; otherwise, NULL.

```
    select
        plans.ID 
  
    from
        PLANS_T plans 
    inner join
        CAREER_GOALS_T careergoals
            on plans.ID=careergoals.PLAN_ID 
   where
     careergoals.goal_id in (39, 41, 42);
```

SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30f59/4

Comment: Adding sample data would help others to better understand your question.

Comment: `select distinct where goal_id in (39, 41, 42) union all select where id is null`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Done, Oracle 19c.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I've updated with a SQLFiddle. The aim is to not use `DISTINCT`. I'm only showing a simplified example, but I'm building a complex criteria query where introducing `DISTINCT` on one column can throw off the multiple NULLs that I need to return individually (some Plans have NULL IDs).

Comment: The example given can easily be rewritten with an EXISTS clause removing the join altogether because you are not bringing in columns from the joined table. Once you get rid of the join you don't need distinct anymore

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you mean with a `SELECT CASE WHEN .. ELSE .. END` statement? a specific code answer would help

Comment: Regarding the EXISTS suggestion, that didn't help with the duplicated rows. Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30f59/37

Comment: in oracle there is similar construction to distinct - unique.
Although you can make group by p.id

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, I think you just want an `exists`.

```
select p.id
from plans_t p
where p.id is null 
or exists (select 1 
           from career_goals_t c
           where p.id=c.plan_id 
           and goal_id in (39, 41, 42));
```

Comment: I'm running this in SqlFiddle, syntax error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30f59/26

Comment: Expected output is "2,3" in this example.If you remove the Join/Where, the expected output is every "1,2,null, null, null, 3, 4". I don't want the duplicated non-NULL Plans under any circumstances.

Comment: Oh in that case, use above. You can get rid of `p.id is null` in case you don't want nulls

Answer (score -1):

Would this work for you?

```
select
    plans.ID  
from
    PLANS_T plans 
where plans.ID in (
  select plan_id from career_goals_t careergoals where
 careergoals.goal_id in (39, 41, 42)
)
```